# joomla chrono form submit notice

Tags: php, joomla, email

i am using chrono forms component in my joomla project for custom form.

After submit form i got a notice

```
 Could not instantiate mail function
```

i cant understand what happen.

anyone tell me..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your mail settings are correct in the Joomla configuration panel. Try setting it as PHPmail and seeing if it works.

Comment: i have already check with PHPmail and sendmail function in admin..not work

Comment: then you should try using smtp